# Adobe Flex on MacOS 10.4

Tags: macos, flash, apache-flex

There is no official up-to-date FlashPlayer (nor support for it) for MacOs 10.4 (PowerPC), but i really need to run a Adobe Flex app on an older Mac.

There is a hack to "install" a current FlashPlayer (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCrAKhv3R_c), and this also works for Adobe Flash swfs.

But if Flex Libraries are used (in this case it is a Flex Project), then the swf is shown as if nothing is loading.

I've already tried to redirect fpdownload.adobe.com (for the crossdomain.xml-request, which might be done automatically) and tried several embedding types.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is this a Flex SWF that you have created?  If so, try changing the framework from a RSL to embedded.  Then it won't try to download SWZ files from Adobe.

Comment: You can try apache flex community if nothing helps. They have mailing lists, i've never done, but you can post your question there if there is a forum. I would strongly agree with Reboog, you should try that if you have code available.